# Fancybox modal, can not populate input fields from database

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, fancybox

i have a project in php codeigniter where data is fetched from the DB, and with a foreach loop it creates rows in a table, each row has an edit button that opens the fancybox modal, in that modal i have 2 input fields, first name and last name that i try to populate them with the current values from the database, in the value section i tried `value="<?php echo $row->first_name ?>`, the problem is that all the rows get the same value, the modal does not get the correct data for each row.

Relevant code:

```
<a data-fancybox data-touch="false" href="#modal" class="btn btn-secondary" style=" margin-bottom:5px;" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" type="button" name="button">Edit</a>

<div id="modal">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/welcome/formValidation">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                            <h3 class="mb-3">Modifica Rapid:</h3>
                            <label for="nume">Nume:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nume" placeholder="Nume" name="nume" value="<?php echo $row->last_name ?>"required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                            <label for="prenume">Prenume</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenume" placeholder="Prenume" name="prenume" value="<?php echo $row->first_name ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 mb-3 text-center">
                            <button style="width:150px;height:50px;" class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Modifica</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you get data in `$row` array by specific `edit id?`

Comment: i use a fetch method from the controller that passes an array to the view, so i don't think i can get data by the id.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, attach the $row id to the modal css id so each modal is unique.

```
<a data-fancybox data-touch="false" href="#modal<?=$row->id;?>" class="btn btn-secondary" style=" margin-bottom:5px;" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" type="button" name="button">Edit</a>
<div id="modal<?=$row->id;?>">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/welcome/formValidation">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                            <h3 class="mb-3">Modifica Rapid:</h3>
                            <label for="nume">Nume:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nume" placeholder="Nume" name="nume" value="<?php echo $row->last_name ?>"required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                            <label for="prenume">Prenume</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenume" placeholder="Prenume" name="prenume" value="<?php echo $row->first_name ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 mb-3 text-center">
                            <button style="width:150px;height:50px;" class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Modifica</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So change

```
<a data-fancybox data-touch="false" href="#modal" class="btn btn-secondary" style=" margin-bottom:5px;" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" type="button" name="button">Edit</a>
```

to

```
<a data-fancybox data-touch="false" href="#modal<?=$row->id;?>" class="btn btn-secondary" style=" margin-bottom:5px;" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" type="button" name="button">Edit</a>
```

by adding the row id to the css to get unique modal id if not all link will call only the last modal.
The same change too for the  modal change

```
<div id="modal">
```

to

```
<div id="modal<?=$row->id;?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i can not change the id to a dynamic one, because the css and js need to use that specific id "modal"

Comment: then use your class for the js that will make thing easy, unless you will go the ajax route

Comment: Are you not getting the data from the model

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is you could assign `data` attributes containing the `last_name` and `first_name` data, and add an `edit-btn` class (as the trigger) to the edit button link :

```html
<a data-fancybox data-touch="false" href="#modal" class="btn btn-secondary edit-btn" data-lastName="<?php echo $row->last_name ?>" data-firstName="<?php echo $row->first_name ?>" style=" margin-bottom:5px;" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" type="button" name="button">Edit</a>

<div id="modal">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/welcome/formValidation">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                            <h3 class="mb-3">Modifica Rapid:</h3>
                            <label for="nume">Nume:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nume" placeholder="Nume" name="nume" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                            <label for="prenume">Prenume</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenume" placeholder="Prenume" name="prenume" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 mb-3 text-center">
                            <button style="width:150px;height:50px;" class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Modifica</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then set the modal input value using each of the data value :

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function () {
    let lastname = $(this).attr("data-lastname");
    let firstname = $(this).attr("data-firstname");
    $('#nume').val(lastname); // set the lastname input inside the modal using the data attribute
    $('#prenume').val(firstname); // set the firstname input inside the modal using the data attribute
});
```